# Trying to get property of non-object when posting data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I've seen this error a few times while handling data, however now I'm just trying to post data to my controller and I don't understand why I see this error as there aren't any objects?

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

The view -

```
<form role="form" class="wizard" type="POST" action="{{ route('data.post') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="seo_score" value="" placeholder="SEO Score e.g. 82" class="col-md-3" maxlength="2"/>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 submit">
      <hr>
      <button type="submit" class="primary-btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The route -

```
Route::get('/admin/overview/{id}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@getSingle',
    'as' => 'account.single',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]);

Route::post('/admin/overview/post', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@postData',
    'as' => 'data.post',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]);
```

The controller -

```
public function postData(Request $request) {
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Where you are redirecting after posting data? In that view you are trying to access property of non-object

Comment: can you elaborate on error message? file, line etc.

Comment: I will insert the passed data, into the database however for testing I just wanted to see if I could access the controller which I couldn't

Comment: Share your view code, all the problem is there i bet it.

Comment: Updated for the full view source code

Comment: try this `public function postData(Request $request) {
   echo 'test';
}` don't redirect it

Comment: I tried the echo test but still get the non-object error

Comment: @CourtneyBall is there any data in your application database?

Comment: Yes of course the data is correctly being output onto the page.

Comment: Check your database, and double check if there is some key field NULL. If found insert manually some related data and it will work.

Comment: If I remove the following line from the view it doesn't throw the error anymore. ` <h1 class="pub-name">{{ $account->name }} overview </h1>`

But it doesn't post the data to the correct, controller so I assume I'm having issues with a similar route?

Comment: Try to return your request only because as I told you the variables cannot be accessed

Comment: from which controller you are sending $account->name value to view? Can you share that controller code? May be you are trying to access Collection data incorrectly .

Comment: Updated the question with the other controller you requested

Comment: try this $account = Accounts::findorfail($id) ; and return only it I think you are accessing an id doesn't exist

Comment: @NinoArmani yes that might be the reason, i mentioned before that Courtney should check the database. And i think it's the accounts table.  check the accounts table and try to access id which exist.Also make sure there is no null value in accounts table.

Comment: + the model name should be Account instead of Accounts, if you use plural then make sure you have defined the table name in model.

Comment: No @Iftikharuddin you mean the name of the table not the name of the model

Comment: Using find or fail I get this error - 'No query results for model'

I have defined the accounts table and there is data that works. The postData controller which was my original question currently just has an echo inside however when I submit the form I get that find or fail error, which shouldn't be the case because that controller I'm posting too doesn't have a return or redirect. 

Which means this whole issue from the original post is to do with the routes, when posting the form it's not using the correct controller... for some reason. I'll look at deleting this and starting again.

Comment: try this $account = Accounts::FindOrFail($id) ;

then dd($account); And change the postData redirect to

`return redirect('admin.account');`

Comment: #original: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "name" => "google"
    "website" => "google.org"
    "created_at" => "2016-09-12 13:42:56"
    "updated_at" => "2016-09-12 13:42:56"
    "location" => ""
  ]

This data is retrieved by a get request so of course after submit the find or fail fails, because I'm not passing the id back to the view. But when you go to the view directly from a link the id is passed via a get request

Comment: I did not read the entire post since I have to go, but you should use {!! csrf_field() !}} instead of {{ }}. It escapes the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

So there were a few things wrong with this first of all the html form had `type="post"` instead of `method="post`. This confused the routes, I was also trying to return to a route which I was passing data back too from another controller. I have now updated the routes and pass the get request through so that doesn't fail.

```
Route::get('/admin/overview/{id}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@getSingle',
    'as' => 'account.single',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]);

Route::post('/admin/overview/{id}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@postSingle',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]);
```